# Order output of Map

Tags: java, json, hashmap

Writing REST API, requests and responses are Json. I make json responses as Map and wondering why its output on screen not in order I've made it?
Example code of my controller, where I construct Map:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ApiErrorNotFound.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public @ResponseBody Map handleDaoException(HttpServletRequest req, ApiErrorNotFound exc) {
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
    Date date = new Date();
    res.put("timestamp", String.valueOf(new Timestamp(date.getTime())));
    res.put("status", String.valueOf(exc.getStatus()));
    res.put("error", "Not Found");
    res.put("exception", ApiErrorNotFound.class.getName());
    res.put("message", exc.getMessage());
    res.put("path", req.getServletPath());
    return res;
}
```

and output is:

```
{
  "exception": "com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.exceptions.ApiErrorNotFound",
  "path": "/room/9",
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "Can't find room with 9 id. (com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.controller.RoomController.getRoomById(RoomController.java:63))",
  "timestamp": "2016-08-21 15:49:01.961",
  "status": "404"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration order of `HashMap` is not guaranteed to be same as the insertion order.

If you want to keep the insertion order when iterating, look at:

[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

To keep the order, try with a `LinkedHashMap`.